# Why the internal implementation of HashSet create a HashMap to store it's values?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashset

I'm a fresh man in coding and now learning the `HashSet` container in Java.What truly puzzled me is that the internal implementation of `HashSet` also create an private `HashMap` object to store it's value and a singleton object `PRESENT`.

So my question is:

- Why would `HashSet` structure need an `HashMap` object to store it's value?(Why not using array structure or linked structure?)
- What is the usage of the singleton object `PRESENT`?(Used to determine whether the insert is successful?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `HashSet` can be viewed as a private case of a `HashMap`, where we only care about the keys.

Using a `HashMap` instance as the `HashSet` implementation is a means to avoid code duplication. Instead of duplicating a significant portion of the `HashMap` code in the `HashSet` class (all the code that manages the array of buckets (including the linked list or tree structure within each bucket), and locates the bucket matching a given key), the JDK developers chose to re-use the `HashMap` code.

The `PRESENT` instance is a dummy instance used as a value in the backing `HashMap` of the `HashSet`. It is used to avoid allocating multiple dummy values.

This is states in a comment:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

Comment: So it means to follow `Open-Closed Principle` ?

Comment: @BinXiao It has been many years since I studied CS, so I don't remember what's that "Open-Closed Principle", but based on a quick googling, it does seem to follow that principle.

Comment: Thank u so much !

Answer (score 2):

> Why would a `HashSet` structure need a `HashMap` object to store it's value?  (Why not using array structure or linked structure?)

Technically, it doesn't need one.

However, it is much easier<sup>1</sup> for the Java team to maintain a single implementation for something as complex as a `HashMap` / `HashSet`.  (Note that the complexity is needed to allow the implementations to work well for a diverse range of use cases.)

There is an memory overhead of 1 reference per entry in implementing `HashSet` as a wrapper for `HashMap`.  However, that is small enough that "they" deem it be acceptable.  And if it is not acceptable *to you* then you are free to implement and maintain your own improved version of the `HashSet` class<sup>2</sup>.

> What is the usage of the singleton object `PRESENT`?

The `PRESENT` instance is an implementation detail.  It is the dummy value used as the value in the wrapped `HashMap` instance.

> Used to determine whether the insert is successful?

In part, yes.

---

<sup>1 - It is revealing that `HashSet` / `HashMap` underwent a major overhaul recently to improve performance ... but the Java team didn't take that opportunity to separate the implementations.</sup>

<sup>2 - You won't be the first person to do that.  However, you are likely to find that it is difficult to substantially improve `HashSet` performance across the board (i.e. for all use-cases) ... and still implement the `java.util.Map` API correctly.  Factoring out the HashMap.Node classes `value` field is probably the only big win.</sup>

Comment: Thank u so much ! I think I should read some books about `Design Patterns`

Comment: I don't actually think that is directly relevant to this question.  In this case, the real answer boils down to business economics: there is insufficient benefit to justify someone (especially Oracle) spending the effort of developing and maintaining a new `HashSet` class that uses a bit less memory and is a tiny bit faster.  If anything, this is an example of the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` is called `HashSet` because it uses `HashMap` to do its work. `HashMap` is a very handy structure that allows you to find information related to some key very quickly, as long as that key has a nice hash function defined for it.

Trivially, if a set was implemented using linked lists, it would be called `LinkedListSet` and not `HashSet`, and it would be much, much slower. Ditto for arrays.

A `PRESENT` singleton is used simply because `HashMap` needs to store something; it does not matter what it is for purposes of `HashSet` as long as something is either there or not, so might as well always be the same thing.

Before `Set` came to JavaScript and Perl, you would see this pattern very often, where one would simply take an object (JS) or a hash (Perl) and stuff a `true` or `1` in it for every present member. So even without the dedicated `HashMap` object, the optimal solution was basically the same idea.

It would be somewhat more memory-efficient to implement the same functionality on a bit-vector, since the only values allowed are non-present or present, but it would involve more work and duplicating existing functionality. The part which finds which index of the array holds the value for which key would be the same, though.